# Why does `slice` have to be unhashable?

Tags: python, hashmap

Why doesn't python make `slice` hashable? In my simple mind you can simply `xor` its `start`, `stop`, and `step` and you will have a good hash.

It will be very useful when we want unordered sets of slices.

Comment: You can always store tuples to be used as the arguments for an on-site call to `slice`:, e.g., `t = (1,2,3); foo[slice(*t)]`

Comment: @chepner True, but say I have an API for the user to supply a set of slices. Using tuple would make the semantic less specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be, it's an accident of history. Slices were made comparable [back in 2001](https://bugs.python.org/issue408326), but they weren't made hashable because it caused an issue to do with setting slices as keys in dicts. So no hash method that returns `hash(tuple(start, stop, step))` was added, although they're otherwise treated like a tuple of their start, stop and step values.

Recently this was raised again, [considered a bug](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84783) and fixed. As of version 3.12, this 22 year old problem will finally go away!

For a workaround, you can use this ([source](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.python/c/SvhkWwSDeIw)) for now, and remove it after everyone is using 3.12 or later:

```py
class hashable_slice:
    """
    Hashable slice wrapper. Can be removed after Python 3.12
    """

    __slots__ = ["slice"]


    def __init__(self, s: slice):
        self.slice = s

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.slice.start, self.slice.stop, self.slice.step))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other == self.slice
```